# Detach event handlers selectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, rich-text-editor

I have a html richText editor. My code structure is like this:

```
function richTextEditor(div)
{

   var self=this;
   self.instanceIdentifier=Math.floor(Date.now());
   //Richtext editor creation logic 
    
   $(document).on('click.'+self.instanceIdentifier,function()
    {
      //some logic
    })

   self.destroy=function()
   { 
     //delete all properties of self
     // detach all listeners
     $(document).off('click.'+self.instanceIdentifier) ;
   }
}
```

Our app is single page application, and there are multiple `richtexteditor` instances opened in different panes. I need to destroy the instance when the node corresponding to this has been removed. Destroy should remove all the event handlers attached by that instance.

So far `Date.now()` for uniquely identifying the handler is working but I think there must be some elegant way to do that.

```
   var div1=$('#notes')[0];
   var editorInstance1=new richTextEditor(div1);
   //remove is not a valid jquery event, its just for illustration
   // I am getting remove event from another library
   $(div1).on('remove',function(){
       editorInstance1.destroy();
    })
```

Please suggest if this is the correct way to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a GUID / UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a GUID or UUID. There is a great answer to this question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript#answer-105074).